# std:.thread in a QT window --> Abort has been called

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, boost-asio

I'm trying to run my ASIO network service in a separate thread while showing a QT Window:

```
QTServer::QTServer(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent)
{
    ui.setupUi(this);

    try
    {
        asio::io_service io_service;
        asio::ip::tcp::endpoint endpoint(asio::ip::tcp::v4(), std::atoi("1337"));
        networkService srv(io_service, endpoint);

        t = std::thread{ [&io_service](){ io_service.run(); } };

    }
    catch (std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cerr << "Exception: " << e.what() << "\n";
    }
}
```

`t` is defined as a member of the MainWindow:

```
class QTServer : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    QTServer(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~QTServer();

private:
    Ui::QTServerClass ui;
    std::thread t;    
};
```

So, I'm getting:

> Debug Error -Abort() Has Been Called

I know that this error usually occurs when a thread is destroyed before join() has been called. However, as the thread is a member variable of the window, I I don't see why this is happening.

Comment: `io_service` is local to the function, but you capture it by *reference*. then the thread runs for longer than the lifetime of the function, hence longer than the lifetime of `io_service`. Not sure if it is your specific problem that causes this error message, but it is *a* problem.

Comment: Why `std::atoi("1337")`? Why not just `1337`? (I assume the code is simplified, and the port actually is a string coming from a config file?)

Comment: Thank you, that was the problem! Too bad I cannot mark your post as the answer :(

Comment: Well I couldn't be bothered/don't have Qt available to test, just pointed out the first obvious problem. Note it is acceptable to answer your own question...